# Style to a variable in VBA

Tags: vba, events, ms-word, shortcut

so i have this code, it replaces every X in the text with "Asunto (1,2,..): Expediente N°". I try to style this part of the code:
What i want is put that text that replaces the X in Arial 11 Bold

`.Text = "Asunto" & " " & i & " " & "Expediente N°"`

i tried this but the style applies to the whole document instead of just that text, i don´t know what else to try

```
     Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "X"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    i = i + 1
    .Text = "Asunto" & " " & i & " " & "Expediente N°"
    .Find.Execute
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
  With .Font
  .Bold = True
  .Name = "Arial"
  .Size = 11
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " Coincidencias."
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I see where you are searching for the value X and replacing it with another value. I don't see where you try to style the text. What style do you want to apply?

Comment: I edited the code so you can see what i did, i tried to style like that but it applies to the whole text not only the text i want to replace with. I already solved the shortcut problem now i just need to style the text under Do while

Comment: The `With .Font` block needs to be inside the `Do While` loop, immediately after `.Text =`

Answer (score 0):

You are NOT applying a Style - all you're doing is overriding whatever Style is already present with hard formatting. Do do with a Style, try for example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "X"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    i = i + 1
    .Text = "Asunto" & " " & i & " " & "Expediente N°"
    .Style = wdStyleStrong
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " instances found."
End Sub
```

In the above, I've employed Word's 'Strong' Style, via the constant wdStyleStrong. If your text is already 11pt Arial, that's all you need. Otherwise, you should define a suitable 11pt Arial Bold character Style and apply that.